# SQL - Count every possible combination

Tags: sql

I have a table with diagnoses and patientids.  The table has one row per diagnosis with a patient id and a diagnosis.

eg

```
Patient ID | Diagnosis
-----------|----------
0          | Asthma
1          | Hypertension
1          | Asthma
2          | Asthma
2          | Hypertension
2          | Cancer
3          | Asthma
```

And I'd like to output something along the lines of

```
Asthma                          | 4
Hypertension                    | 2
Asthma & Hypertension           | 2
Asthma, Hypertension and Cancer | 1
```

How can I count the number of diagnoses combinations with the names of the Diagnosis?

i.e.  x number of patients have Asthma, x number of patients have asthma and hypertension, x number of patients have diabetes, heart disease, lung disease, cancer, etc.

Some patients have as many as 12 diagnoses.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results (in a tabular format).  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Gordon, does the database **really** matter in this case? It's a question of approach, surely, not syntax? And he does describe the data pretty well

Comment: How many total unique diagnoses do you have?

Comment: With 12 possible diagnoses, a query that would return a count for all possible combinations would return 12! rows.  12! = 479,001,600 rows.  Is that really a usable set of data?

Comment: Joshua, I've added some example data - I was unsure if you wanted duplication in the second table, however, so please edit if it's wrong! I've assumed that you want to count all patients with Asthma (even if they have other conditions), rather than only counting patients who **just** have asthma, and have no other conditions

Comment: @Kevin..it would be 2**12 = 4096 combinations, not 12!

Comment: @vkp There's too little information to determine the number of combinations as the number of elements in the set of diagnoses to choose from is unknown, but lets says there are 100 possible diagnoses, then you can choose 1 in 100 ways, 2 in 4950 ways, 4 in almost 4 million ways and 12 in ~1*10**15 ways (If I remember how to calculate combinations right).

Comment: yes @jpw..you would arrive at (2 power 100) if there were 100 possible diagnoses. This would also include patients who had no diagnoses at all. So it can be (2 power 100)-1 or (2 power 100) depending on the need.

Comment: @vkp, you are correct. My math was wrong.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: This is possible, but it requires a lot of manual writing, and knowing the max amount of diagnoses that a patient has (OP mentioned 12)

Comment: @Samcd: there is actually no manual writing necessary, see my SQL Fiddle link in my previous comment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Is there a way to do array[diagnosis] in other DBMS?

Comment: @Samcd As far as I know Postgres is the only DBMS that can do array operations like that. But you could do that with plain string concatenation as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fb6c9/3 It might not be that efficient though. Plus in Oracle this would have a limit of 4000 Bytes for the complete list of diagnosis elements (or 32k in Oracle 12 if extended strings are enabled)

Answer (score 1):

This might require editing from someone more well versed than myself in using `FOR XML` to concatenate rows, but this is one way to do it:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
PatientID,
STUFF(
    (
    SELECT ', ' + [Diagnosis] 
    FROM Table 
    WHERE (PatientID = B.PatientID) 
    ORDER BY Diagnosis
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
    ,1,1,'') AS Diagnoses
FROM Table B
  )

SELECT Diagnoses,COUNT(DISTINCT PatientID) as Total
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Diagnoses
```

Basically, you are creating a concatenated value for all diagnoses for each patient, after ordering by Diagnosis (so that i.e. `'Condition1,Condition2'` is not read differently from `'Condition2,Condition1'`), then creating a second query to get the count for each combination

Comment: @jpw You are right. I don't have a lot of experience using FOR XML, so I figured that they would be automatically grouped and that would take care of duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can do this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive all_diags as (
   select patient_id, diagnosis, diagnosis as diagnosis_list
   from diagnostics
   union all 
   select c.patient_id, c.diagnosis, p.diagnosis_list||','||c.diagnosis
   from diagnostics c
     join all_diags p on p.patient_id = c.patient_id and p.diagnosis < c.diagnosis
)
select diagnosis_list, count(*)
from all_diags
group by diagnosis_list
order by diagnosis_list;
```

Note that the keyword `recursive` is required by the SQL standard but not all DBMS actually support using that keyword.

There is a difference to your expected output though: my solution also returns the combinations: `Cancer`, `Cancer,Hypertension` and `Asthma,Cancer` which you didn't include in your sample output.

Here is a SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/21087/1